# 2 spark lists drag&drop: handle change

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have 2 spark lists with items, drag&drop enabled (mxml application, flash builder 4). Everything works fine, I can drag and drop items from the one list to the other. I've been searching a lot but I can't find it (probably because I'm using the wrong keywords).

Let's say that I want to 'handle' when an Item changes from list. So

```
LIST 1          LIST 2
item1           item 2
                item 3
```

It works fine when I drag Item 3 to List 1, but how can I handle this event? I want to 'save' the changes. I think about looping the whole list when there's a 'change', but I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Can someone give me more advice or help me out?

Thanks a lot!
(And sorry if this question has already been asked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle by listening the event `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE`:

```
myList.dataProvider.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onCollectionChangeHandle);
```

That will fire an `event.kind == CollectionEventKind.*` ([see here](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEventKind.html#ADD)) each time you make some change, so you can save the changes as you want.

Also there is the option by listening `DragEvent.DRAG_COMPLETE` event:

```
myList.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_COMPLETE, onDragCompleteHandle)
```

Which `event.dragSource` has the data being dragged.

Comment: Also should be good you take a look at the links that buddy **iND** have posted too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Adobe has a pretty good example of this functionality . . . see the [example of handling drag-drop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fef).  Also, see [this example of maintaining type info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfd.html#WS7d89194359d2921c55a0a0ac1247d0abc10-8000), if that is the problem.